# How to calculate SKEW.P in Excel for a grouped data?

Tags: excel, skew

Here is my original table

[image]

It is obviously skewed to the right (SKEW must be negative) . However when i apply SKEW.P function in excel it gives a positive number 1.4

I think the reason is because the data is grouped. So to get the real SKEW.P I will need to ungroup data, and have half a million elements that will look like this: 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2..........

Is there any easier way to estimate SKEW.P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has Office 365 then we can use:

```
=SKEW.P(INDEX(Table1[Group],MATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(Table1[Number of Elements in Group]),,0),SUMIF(OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[Number of Elements in Group]],0,0,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Table1[Number of Elements in Group]))),"<>"))))
```

If not then we use:

```
=SKEW.P(INDEX(Table1[Group],N(IF({1},MATCH(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,SUM(Table1[Number of Elements in Group])))-1,SUMIF(OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[Number of Elements in Group]],0,0,ROW(Table1[Number of Elements in Group])-MIN(ROW(Table1[Number of Elements in Group]))+1),"<>"))))))
```

And confirm as an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much . But i cant get it to work. Could you please replace `Table1` with an `Array`. It says there is a problem with the formula.

Comment: You have a table in your example so I am not sure what you mean.